# Command runs from CMD but not from batch-file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I can open the cash drawer by running the following command in `CMD`:

```
ECHO ^G>LPT1
```

Problem is that when I run this command from a batch file, nothing happens.
I added a `timeout` to see what command actually runs and it seems like my command is automatically replaced with the following when it is run:

```
ECHO G 1>LPT1
```

How can I run my original command from a batch-file?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Double up the caret from `^` to `^^` as ^ alone is the escape character.

Comment: Thank you for your response, also how can I get rid of space and number 1 that is added automatically?

Comment: Did you test it?  The 1 is displayed on the screen but is not used in the command.  It's a signifier of the STDOUT stream. (standard out)

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me:

As Josefz Said:

Run CMD Prompt as administrator and type:

```
echo @echo(•^>COM5>c:\Drawer.bat
```

Change COM5 to whatever port your printer is on. I'm using a *STAR TSP100IIIECO USB* Using the virtual com port supplied with the star driver.

The result when opened in notepad is:

> echo  > COM5

As you will see notepad cannot display the special character but running the bat successfully kicks the drawer.

I know it's an old thread but hopefully this helps someone out.

Answer (score 0):

```
ECHO G 1>LPT1
```

is exactly the same as

```
ECHO G>LPT1
```

the first is correct and the second is for msdos compatability and what we mostly use. CMD fixes it as it's in a batch file rather than typed and it gets to change what you see.

However to enter Ctrl + G in a text file use CMD redirection

```
echo echo [ctrl+g]^>lpt1
```

if 32 bit use edit.com. In Edit press Ctrl P then Ctrl G (it will look different to cmd).

Comment: To confirm, "echo echo [ctrl+g]>>lpt1" is equivalent to "ECHO ^G>LPT1" but can be run from the .bat file rather than CMD?

Comment: I tried the suggestions above  but the register is still not opening, if I open CMD and type in ECHO ^G>LPT1 it opens but if I try to do the same through a batch file, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

If I can understand, you need to send `BELL` sound character (ASCII `0x07`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) to the `LPT1` device.

Unfortunately, my text editor (and `notepad.exe` as well) brings *Goto line* dialogue after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and another method <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>07</kbd> [advised here](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) erroneously [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)s to ASCII `0x95`. Here's my workaround: from `cmd` command line, type

```
echo @echo(•^>LPT1>D:\bat\SO\32642290a.bat
```

where `•` represents either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>07</kbd> and displays `^G` on a monitor.

Result:

[image: 32642290a_bat]

Result in hexadecimal view:

[image: 32642290a_bat_HEX]

Comment: I tried the suggestions above  but the register is still not opening, if I open CMD and type in ECHO ^G>LPT1 it opens but if I try to do the same through a batch file, nothing happens.

Comment: @Alex `type D:\bat\SO\32642290a.bat` should display `@echo(>LPT1` accompanied the `BELL` sound. The same sound as `ECHO ^G` (without redirecting to a `LPT` device).